# Android Button that link to paypal donation page directly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, paypal

I have a site `"http://samplesite.org/give/"` with a paypal donate button which is essentially a form like this

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXXXX" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" border="0" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" 
    name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif">
<p>
<img width="1" height="1" border="0" 
   src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="">
</p>
</form>
```

and if it is clicked, it will go to this paypal site:

```
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?
cmd=_flow&SESSION=y0Kn8GFSDCCCEpZkHLs
b30_vQ29XhQzDf6FDSAfsd5643pWai7M
ogFN3QG&dispatch=5885d80432b1f8e26423443aee
8d5542c5a2cgfdg45d3543gdf9a5e
```

I can make a button where it link to `http://samplesite.org/give/` but if that's the case, user will be presented with page then they have to click the paypal button again.

How can I make the button link it directly to the page that looks like after the paypal button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick() for the button, just call the following code:

```
String url = "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=y0Kn8GFSDCCCEpZkHLsb30_vQ29XhQzDf6FDSAfsd5643pWai7MogFN3QG&dispatch=5885d80432b1f8e26423443aee8d5542c5a2cgfdg45d3543gdf9a5e";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: but then the session will be wrong, and cause problem

Answer (score 0):

You should send your user to this page: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXX

You can also find the url by clicking on the Email tab on the page with the generated code.